# Any Linux distributions that compiles Xen source without system modifications?

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen

Are there any Linux distributions which after a clean install compile Xen 4.1?

So far I have tried installing the following:

- Ubuntu 12.04 (Compiles fine with dependencies but tools like XM have Python errors, due to Python installing the libraries in the wrong directory. All the fixes that are suggested online simply didn't work)
- Debian 6 (requires patching and recompiling the kernel, something I'd rather not get into)

I need it to compile from source as I may need to make modifications to parts.

Bit of an unusual question but I hope there's a quick answer to this that someone knows.
Would really appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work on debian testing. It will be easier if you use debian prepared sources.